# selecting data in access by conditional merging

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access query which return data in the form of:

[image]

What I want is to have this data on the basis of Study Id; if for any study id, text data i.e reasons are the same and Soption is at least 'true' for one record then it should show 'true', otherwise it should show 'false'.

i.e

[image]

Notice if both Soptions for a reason are 'no' then the Soption is retained as 'no', else Soption is set to 'yes' and the rows are combined as a single row.

How can I achieve this functionality in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT StudyID, TextData, Max(SOption) as SOption2
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY StudyID, TextData
ORDER BY StudyID, TextData
```

When you group by, use "Max(SOption) as SOption2".  Since Y is greater than N, it will return 'Yes' for any record that has both 'Yes' and 'No'.